# Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/FileDownload'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have installed both `@material-ui/core` and `@material-ui/icons`.

I am trying to import *"FileDownloadIcon"* from Material icons.

Installing *"@material-ui/core"*:

```
npm i @material-ui/core
```

Installing *"@material-ui/icons"*:

```
npm i @material-ui/icons
```

This is the way I am trying to import *"FileDownloadIcon"*:

```
import FileDownloadIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FileDownload';
<div className="download-file">
        <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                onClick={() => getResume()}
            >
            <FileDownloadIcon />
            Download Resume
        </Button>
</div>
```

But it's occurring error like this *"Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/FileDownload' in 'E:\frontend\src\component\Details'"*

Where is the problem?

Comment: I think you need to install @mui/material

Comment: It seems like you are confused using Material-ui v5 and v4. You installed v4 icons and tried to import v5 icons.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**FileDownload** icon is added in v5, it does not exist in v4. You can search for v4 icons [here](https://v4.mui.com/components/material-icons/). To use the v5 icon in the older version of MUI, just go and copy the source code [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-docs/src/svgIcons/FileDownload.js):

```
function FileDownload(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon {...props}>
      <path d="M19 9h-4V3H9v6H5l7 7 7-7zM5 18v2h14v-2H5z" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}
```

If you are using Material UI v5 already, it means you're missing the icon package. Follow the installation guide [here](https://mui.com/components/icons/#material-icons) to install:

```
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

Answer (score 11):

`npm install @mui/icons-material`

(OR)

`npm install -g @material-ui/icons`

Comment: you should be giving some details on the difference between the 2 npm install options you have provided

Answer (score 7):

use the migration from v4 to v5 following this link https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/

you can do:

```
// with npm
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

or this :

1. `npm install @mui/material @mui/styles`
2. `npm install @emotion/react @emotion/styled`

Comment: npm install @mui/icons-material --force   worked for me

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be using v5 of Material-UI. Use the following:

```
import { FileDownload } from "@mui/icons-material";
```

Notice the name of the icon, omitting `Icon`. Then use it with the button:

```
<div className="download-file">
  <Button
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    onClick={() => getResume()}
    startIcon={<FileDownload />}>
     Download Resume
  </Button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Before proceeding, ensure that you have installed `@material-ui/icons` by running the following command `npm install @mui/icons-material` for material ui version 5 and `npm install @material-ui/icons` for version 4:

If you are utilizing React Material UI version 5, import the required icon like this:

```js
import FileDownloadIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FileDownload';
```

If you encounter the Can't resolve issue while using React Material UI version 4 and you have imported it using the first method, follow these steps to resolve the problem:

Instead of importing the icon as:

```js
import FileDownloadIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FileDownload';
```

You should import it like this:

```js
import CheckCircleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/FileDownload";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install - [@mui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/material) but you've installed [material-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/icons).

But I'm facing issue if you can help then do check below two links.

1. I've forced installed [mui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76705303/mui-dependency-error-npm-install-mui-icons-material).
2. As a result getting module not found [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76710917/module-not-found-in-mui-icons)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add '//' comment and run. Then again run without the comment. This may help you