# Module not found in mui-icons

Tags: material-ui, modern-ui

I'd resolve npm install error by forcing but now getting other error so posting this question.

1. Issue resolve relate to `npm install @mui/icons-material` :- [Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76705303/mui-dependency-error-npm-install-mui-icons-material)
2. but now getting below error after running `npm start`

Failed to compile.

```
./node_modules/@mui/icons-material/Delete.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react/jsx-runtime'
```

but I had found 2 Delete.js files on above given path not sure why still getting this error.

I've checked the below pages

1. https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/
2. https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple things. Hope my solution will come handy for you.
[Blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-to-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version)

Out of that 2 ans are very interesting.

1. from Sibiraj - (This is risky solution as you have to delete node modules and package-lock files. As after deleting this files when I ran the npm install I got error. Since I had the copy I recovered this files.)

This feature has been introduced in `npm v5`. update to `npm` using `npm install -g npm@latest` and
to update `package.json`

delete `/node_modules` and `package-lock.json` (if you have any)

run `npm update`. this will update the dependencies `package.json` to the latest.

to update to very latest version. you can go with `npm-check-updates`.

2. From Andrei Gec (I did not tried this as I already went for option 1, but option 2 looks safe as it gives exact same file: I crossed checked)

If you're looking for an easier solution that doesn't involve installing npm packages, I'd checkout [updatepackagejson.com](https://updatepackagejson.com/)

Solution to above problem run the below line of code. [Link](https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/?query=delete)

```
npm install @mui/icons-material @mui/material @emotion/styled @emotion/react
```

I was getting error while running this in hyper as my package.json was not updated. And due package-lock even after running `npm-check-updates` package.json did not got updated.